# How to align text with line?

Tags: react-native

I want to achieve this below thing. Putting text between two lines. But I am failing to do so far.
.

[image]

So far what I achieved is look like this

[image]

My code is

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
          <View
            style={{
              width: Dimensions.get('screen').width / 2 - 20,
              height: 3,
              borderStyle: 'solid',
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              marginBottom: 15,
              marginTop: 8,
              left: 0,
            }}
          />
          <Text
            style={[
              {
                fontSize: 18,
                padding: 5,
                marginBottom: 10,
                color: 'black',
                
              },
              global.fontNormal,
            ]}>
            {'or'}
          </Text>
          <View
            style={{
              width: Dimensions.get('screen').width / 2 - 20,
              height: 3,
              borderStyle: 'solid',
              backgroundColor: 'black',
              marginBottom: 15,
              marginTop: 8,
              right: 0,
            }}
          />
        </View>
```

Is there a better way to achieve that?
Suggest me how to achieve that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add alignItems:'center'
As when you make the flex direction row then the alignitems property aline the content vertically and justifycontents aline items horizontally

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between', flex:1 , alignItems:'center'}}>
```

Sample code: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/center-line